# Data binding with ListPicker issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to bind the data from linq xml in isolated storage. The data templates (ItemTemplate and FullModeItemTemplate) work fine and only show the value saved in the element or attribute in the  xml document.

```
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindName}" Margin="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16,21,0,20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindName}" Margin="16,0,0,0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

However, although on the listpicker when selected it appears to use this name, the actual value held by the list picker is:

```
appname.pagename + namestringusedwhensetting
```

The name of the string comes from where I set it I presume. I am using this method:

```
    public class BindingSetter
    {
        string sValue;

        public string SValueN
        {
            get { return sValue; }
            set { sValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

So it is returning:

```
appname.pagename + sValue
```

I have used binding throughout my application and have not had this problem before so i am a bit stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jamie, you're not getting much response; it's sounds a bit weird at the moment, and it might be because its actually being weird, which is all the more reason to explain it all very clearly, as if to a child. Albeit a child that knows XAML and C#.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have updated it to try to explain more clearly

Comment: I am not quite sure what's going wrong? In your XAML you have to DataTemplates and both have TextBlocks that bind to BindName property. Now, what's up with appname.pagename + namestringusedwhensetting? I am completely lost after your XAML post and cannot get your problem.

Comment: The textblocks in the listpicker template display the value from the xml in isolated storage so on the surface it looks ok. However when you select one from the list although thanks to the itemtemplate it appears fine, if you use the .selecteditem it returns appname.pagename + sValue

Comment: To check im doing it right... how do i retreive the value of the selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work it out. To use the value on the selected item I used:

```
((appname.PageName.ClassUsedToBindData)(ListPickerName.SelectedItem)).String
```

eg.

```
((calculator.MainPage.CalculateBinding)(FunctionSelector.SelectedItem)).Function
```

Hope this helps anyone who is struggling like I was!